# SQLITE select by group and limit results for each group

Tags: php, sqlite

I have the following SQLITE table:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tit1 | cat1 | time1 |
| tit2 | cat3 | time2 |
| tit3 | cat1 | time3 |
| tit4 | cat1 | time4 |
| tit5 | cat3 | time5 |
| tit6 | cat2 | time6 |
| tit7 | cat1 | time7 |

I want to SELECT all rows grouped by COL2, WHERE COL2 == cat1 or cat2, but LIMIT the results to max 2 rows for each group and ORDER the results by COL3 DESC.

So, for instance, in this case I want to get only:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tit7 | cat1 | time7 |
| tit4 | cat1 | time4 |
| tit6 | cat2 | time6 |

Is it possible to obtain this with (possibly) one or max 2 queries?

So far I tried this, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM "tablename" WHERE "COL2" = "cat1" OR "COL2" = "cat2" GROUP BY "COL2" ORDER BY "COL3" DESC LIMIT 2
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the table and use ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2 ORDER BY COL3 DESC) rn 
  FROM tablename  
)
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY COL2, COL3 DESC
```